# Proof check: Necessary and sufficient condition for $\langle x^r\rangle\subseteq\langle x^s\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm just wondering if I've come to the right conclusion here, because something seems off, and I don't know why. Any room for improvement otherwise is appreciated as well.

Chapter 4, Problem 68 in Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*:
Suppose that $|x|=n$. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $r$ and $s$ such that $\langle x^r\rangle\subseteq\langle x^s\rangle$.

Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups (FTCG): Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Moreover, if $|\langle a\rangle|=n$, then the order of any subgroup of $\langle a\rangle$ is a divisor of $n$; and, for each positive divisor $k$ of $n$, $\langle a\rangle$ has exactly one subgroup of order $k$ - namely, $\langle a^\frac{n}{k}\rangle$.

*Claim:* $\langle x^r\rangle\subseteq\langle x^s\rangle$ if, and only if, $|x^r|\vert|x^s|$

*Proof:* First, if $|\langle x^r\rangle|=j$ and $|\langle x^s\rangle|=k$, then $j,k|n$, and these are the only subgroups contained in $\langle x\rangle$ of orders $j$ and $k$, respectively, by the FTCG. Suppose $\langle x^r\rangle\subseteq\langle x^s\rangle$; then $j|k$, by the FTCG. Suppose $j|k$; then by the FTCG, $\langle x^s\rangle$ has exactly one subgroup of order $j$, and since there is only one subgroup of order $j$ in $\langle x\rangle$, this subgroup is $\langle x^r\rangle$, so $\langle x^r\rangle\subseteq \langle x^s\rangle$. Thus, since $|\langle x^r\rangle|=|x^r|$ and $|\langle x^s\rangle|=|x^s|$, $\langle x^r\rangle\subseteq\langle x^s\rangle$ if, and only if, $|x^r|\vert|x^s|$. //

Now, another theorem points out that if $|x|=n$, then $|x^k|=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$. Thus, we have the following: $|x^r|\vert|x^s|\Leftrightarrow m\frac{n}{\gcd(n,r)}=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,s)}\Leftrightarrow m\gcd(n,s)=\gcd(n,r)\Leftrightarrow\gcd(n,s)|\gcd(n,r)$.

Therefore, the necessary and sufficient condition on $r$ and $s$ is $\gcd(n,s)|\gcd(n,r)$.

Comment: Quicker: $\langle x^r\rangle\subseteq\langle x^s\rangle$ iff $x^r\in\langle x^s\rangle$ iff $x^r=x^{ms}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ iff $r=ms+kn$ for some $m,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ iff $r$ is divisible by $\gcd(n,s)$.  Note you don't need $\gcd(r,n)$ because $\gcd(n,s)$ automatically divides $n$.

Comment: @user10354138 Hadn't actually thought about those last two biconditionals; I guess I got a bit of tunnel vision trying to think about the concepts from the chapter. Thank you!